# How to scan a a specific repos/folders in linux and delete everything else that gets generated

Tags: linux, shell

In my software build process , I am generating specific files inside 2 specific folder. These two specific folders exist inside a repo (e.g  x/y/folder1 & x/y/folder2). Now after my build process is finished I see some files also generated inside 'x/y' folder (eg x/y/file1  & x/y/file2 &..). These files are irrelevant. How can I scan my folder after build process is finished and remove everything (all files eg x/y/file1  & x/y/file2 &..) except x/y/folder1 & x/y/folder2. I would like to include this check point in my build script itself (after build process is finished) to first scan for the relevant folder (e.g x/y) and remove everything except x/y/folder1 & x/y/folder2 to give a cleaner result.

I am using : Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.11

Comment: You can use `find x/y -name 'folder*' | xargs rm -f ` for file removal

Comment: Excellent!! can we also remove folders (just like files) other than the mentioned one, sorry for the stupid question but just landed into the world of shell.

Comment: Yes, you can. Just put the correct name mask and replace `rm -f` with `rm -rf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> find . -type f  ! -path "./folder1/*" ! -path "./folder2/*" | xargs rm
>   -f

or this id you would like to remove files and folders and just keep the ones you want

> find . ! -path "./folder1/" ! -path "./folder2/" -exec rm -rf {} \;

Comment: Excellent!! can we also remove folders other than the mentioned one, sorry for the stupid question but just landed into the world of shell.

Comment: yes you can here is the command . basically we removed the type f and made the rm part of the find .   "find .! -path "./folder1/" ! -path "./folder2/"  -exec rm -rf {} \;"